# Is it possible to use loops in IntelliJ live templates?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I noticed that IntelliJ has syntax for "set", "if" and "foreach" statements to build file templates.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-and-code-templates.html.  However, it doesn't seem like this is possible with live templates.  Am I doing something wrong, or do they just not have this support?

Basically I'm looking for the same functionality as TextMate's snippets.  It would be nice to create a script that would generate or transform text exactly how I want using tools like bash, perl, python or php (but I'd settle for #if and #foreach if that's possible too).  And it looks like the IntelliJ TextMate plugin doesn't support this either, so is there any other plugin that would accomplish this?

Comment: The answer was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405836/how-to-pass-variable-to-groovy-code-in-intellij-idea-live-templates-groovy-scrip

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to this.  It looks like you can use Groovy scripts in live templates with the `groovyScript("groovy code")` predefined function

Comment: please tell us how. i am curious too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. Use groovyScript in variable. Example:
`groovyScript("def TABLE_NAME=\"${_1}\"; def resultStr=''; for(i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {     resultStr+=\"\"\"     \n     CREATE TABLE ${TABLE_NAME}_${i}     PARTITION OF ${TABLE_NAME}     FOR VALUES IN (${i});     \"\"\"; }; return resultStr;", clipboard())`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGlhD.png)