# How to pass variable to groovy code in Intellij IDEA live templates groovy script?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, live-templates

I have a `groovyScript` in my `Intellij` IDEA live template, like this :

```
groovyScript("D:/test.groovy","", v1)
```

on my `D:/test.groovy` i have a code like this:

```
if ( v1 == 'abc') {
    'abc'
}
```

Now I want to pass v1 variable into test.groovy ,can any one help me how can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

For exemplification purposes I made a live template which is printing a comment with the current class and current method.

This is how my live template is defined:

[image]

And here is how I edited the ***variableResolvedWithGroovyScript*** variable:

[image]

The **Expression** for the given variable has the follwing value:

```
groovyScript("return \"// Current Class:\" + _1 + \". Current Method:\"+ _2 ", className(),methodName())
```

As you can see, in this case the _1(which acts like a variable in the groovy script) takes the value of the first parameter which is the class name, and the _2 takes the value of the 
second parameter which is the method name. If another parameter is needed the _3 will be used in the groovy script to reference the given parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to groovyScript macro are bound to script variables named _1, _2 etc. This is also described at groovyScript help at [Edit Template Variables Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/edit-template-variables-dialog.html) / [Live Template Variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-template-variables.html).

Comment: can you please provide an working example for passing variables on D:/test.groovy ?
I have tried this _1, _2 on groovyScript and it worked.
but not working on D:/test.groovy

Comment: Works for me. I have /home/peter/test.groovy:
_1 + " separator " + _2
and have a variable:
groovyScript("/home/peter/test.groovy", qualifiedClassName(), "suffix").

This works and produces "NullTest separatorsuffix" in a class named NullTest.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

I was needing to calculate a CRC32 of the qualified class name using live models

I used it like this:

```
groovyScript("   
def crc = new java.util.zip.CRC32().with { update _1.bytes; value }; 
return Long.toHexString(crc);  
", qualifiedClassName())
```

[image]

then the result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html), your variables are available as `_1`, `_2`, etc. Please note that variables are passed without dollar signs (so only *v1* instead of *$v1$*)

So your test script should look like

```
if ( _2 == 'abc') {
    'abc'
}
```