# PyCharm: how to run some script to analyze selected text and insert result in editor?

Tags: pycharm

Are there any way, except writing own plugin, to run some code, which will analyse selected text, got result based on it, and finally inserts the result into editor (such simple things even MS Word can do with Visual Basic)?

Answer (score 0):

Use groovyScript in Live template (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405836/how-to-pass-variable-to-groovy-code-in-intellij-idea-live-templates-groovy-scrip/49157447#49157447))

1. Go to (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) Settings/LiveTemplates
2. Add (+) user template, i.e. `testGroovy`
3. Enter Template text, i.e. `$grv$ [[$grv1$]]`, this will add 2 variables in template: `grv` and `grv1`. First we will enter after template activation, second will be processed by groovy script.
4. Press Edit variables
5. Enter expression for `grv1`, i.e. `groovyScript("\"test${_1}\"", grv)`, this will acrivate groovy code inside quotes, and will pass `grv` as first parameter. We use it under `_1` alias inside groovy script. Check Skip if defined.
6. Ok, Ok, Go to Editor, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for Live template lists, type name of template `testGroovy`, Enter. Enter some input for `grv` variable. `grv2` will be defined by our groovy code, so result will be like `123 [[test123]]`, where `123` is our input.
7. Also we can use `clipboard()` as default value for `grv` to process clipboard content, or directly pass it for groovyScript as argument if we don't what user input.
8. To run groovy script from file use file name in double quotes, instead of groovy code, i.e. `groovyScript("C:/Groovy/script.groovy" , grv)`. Take a note on **forward** slashes, otherwise it will not work.